# python3, how to download zip files

Tags: python

I have a simple script that download zip files to the folder, i don't know what i am doing wrong, the files are always corrupted,I attached a reproducible example, first I get the list of files, which works fine, but when I download those files, it complains that the zip is corrupted.

```
import re ,shutil
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = "http://nemweb.com.au/Reports/Current/Dispatch_SCADA/"
result = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
pattern = re.compile(r'[\w.]*.zip')
filelist = pattern.findall(result)


for x in filelist:
     with urlopen(url) as source, open(x, 'w+b') as target:
          shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
```

Comment: open file in text editor - maybe you get HTML with warning for bots/scripts.

Comment: you always use the same `url` to HTML page with links. You have to get urls from links and then download.

Comment: that's what I did

Comment: Isn't every file a copy of your listing? You don't seem to change `url`. Did you mean to assemble a URL based on `x`?

Comment: you get only file names but not urls in links to these files. And you always download HTML from `http://nemweb.com.au/Reports/Current/Dispatch_SCADA/`

Comment: damn it, so easy

Comment: I think that `url + '/' + x` could get file

Comment: oops, yes of course, sorry i just miss, it please add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always use the same `url` to HTML page

You have to download `url + "/" + x`

```
 for x in filelist:
     with urlopen(url + "/" + x) as source, open(x, 'w+b') as target:
         shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
```